# SSH keys fail for one user

Tags: ssh, debian, user-management

I just set up a new Debian server. I disabled root SSH and password auth, so you've gotta use a key file.

For my primary user, everything works exactly as expected. I used `ssh-keygen -t dsa` and got myself a public and private key. Put one in authorized keys, put the other in a pem file locally.

I wanted to create a user that I can deploy things with, so I did basically the same process. I `adduser`ed it, made a `.ssh` folder, ran `ssh-keygen -t dsa` (I also tried RSA), put the keys in their appropriate locations.

No luck. I'm getting a `Permission denied (publickey)` error. When I use the exact same keys as the account that works, same error. When I enable password authentication, I can log in via SSH with the password.

How do I debug this?

**EDIT**

Verbose ssh output (deployer.pem is proper key):

```
debug2: key: /Users/eli/.ec2/deployer.pem (0x100126830)
debug2: key: /Users/eli/.ec2/deployer.pem (0x100126b30)
debug2: key: /Users/eli/.ec2/deployer.pem (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/eli/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: eli.pem
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/eli/.ec2/deployer.pem
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/eli/.ec2/deployer.pem
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/eli/.ec2/deployer.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Try `ssh -v user@host` to get more debug output from the client. (and `ssh -vv` for even more).

Comment: Look in the server logs for hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two parts: first, turn up debugging on your ssh sever.  Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and increase LogLevel to DEBUG.  Then force your ssh server to reload it's config with `killall -HUP <sshd pid>`.

That will cause the server to add much more details to your `/var/log/secure` and/or `/var/log/auth` logfiles.

Secondly (actually you cant try this first), increase the debug level on the client side.  ssh in to the box with

> `$ ssh -vvv hostname`

and that will print out lots more info about where the process is failing.

If you do turn up the debug level on your ssh server, don't forget to turn it back down when you are finished.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging help, the real issue was the my .ssh directory on the server had crazy permissions. All of the files in it had the correct permissions, though.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked the permissions on the key files? The `.ssh/id_dsa` file should be 600 and owned by the user. Run `ssh -v root@host` to see if this is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the user's home directory, the .ssh directory under the user's home directory, or the user's authorized_keys file are writable by anyone other than the user (either group or other), key authentication will outright fail because the .ssh/authorized_keys file can no longer be trusted (as another user could then replace or modify it and thus log in as that user).

Try:

```
chmod go-w ~USER ~USER/.ssh ~USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and see if that clears up your problem.

Answer (score 2):

`chown -R username. /home/username/.ssh`

`chmod 700 /home/username/.ssh`

`chmod 400 /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa.pub`

`chmod 600 /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few tips based on the issues I ran into while trying to get ssh working via Pubkey Authentication ie ssh rsa:

in addition to the above tips (permissions, -vvv):
- on the destination server, check the account info via passwd -S username or passwd -s username.  The output will look like [username][stat][pwchg][min][max][warn].  if the [stat] column says LK, you need to unlock the account passwd -u username.  if the [pwchg] date is older than [max] days, you need to change the max days or change the password on username via passwd -x 999 or passwd username

example:

```
# uname -n
myserver

# pwd
/export/home/santac
# ls -l .ssh
-rw-------   1 santac   users        796 Jul  8 00:27 authorized_keys
# cat .ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAABBBCCCboogaboogaAAABBBCCCidonthinkyougetthatthisisbogusbutwhattheheck== santac@otherserv
# date
Wed Jul  8 00:55:10 GMT 2015
# passwd -S santac
santac    LK    03/05/14     7   60     10
(note stat is LK or locked)
# passwd -u santac
# passwd -S santac
santac    PS    03/05/14     7   60     10
(note [pwchg] date is older than 60 days)
# passwd santac
Enter New Password:
Confirm New Password:
# passwd -S santac
santac    PS    07/08/15     7   60     10
(all good now)

FROM THE OTHER SERVER:
# uname -n
otherserv
# pwd
/export/home/santac
# ls -l .ssh
-rw-------   1 santa   users       1675 Jul  6 20:23 id_rsa
-rw-------   1 santa   users        394 Jul  6 20:23 id_rsa.pub
# cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAABBBCCCboogaboogaAAABBBCCCidonthinkyougetthatthisisbogusbutwhattheheck== santac@otherserv

LOOKS GOOD...
```